# How to use sed to group date/time?

Tags: unix, sed, command-line

I have a text

```
7304628626|duluth/superior|18490|2016|volvo|gas|49230|automatic|sedan|white|mn|46.815216|-92.178109|2021-04-10T08:46:33-0500
```

I want to change text `2021-04-10T08:46:33-0500` to `10/04/2021 08:46:33`

I try use this command

```sh
sed -n "s/|\([0-2][0-9][0-9][0-9]\)-\([0-1][0-9]\)-\([1-3][0-9]\)\(T\)\([0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]\)\(-[0-1][0-9][0][0]\)/|\3\/\2\/\1 \5 /p" filename
```

but some text hasn't change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your shown samples, please try following `sed` program.

`sed -E 's/(.*\\|)([0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})T([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})-.*/\1\4\/\3\/\2 \5/'  Input_file`

***Explanation:*** Using `sed` program's back reference capability here to store matched values into temp buffer and use them later on in substitution. In main `sed` program using `-E` option to enable ERE(extended regular expression) then using `s` option to perform substitution. First creating 5 capturing group to match `7304628626|duluth/superior|18490|2016|volvo|gas|49230|automatic|sedan|white|mn|46.815216|-92.178109|`(in first capturing group), `2021`(in 2nd capturing group), `04`(in 3rd capturing group), `10`(in 4th) and 08 :46:33(in 5th capturing group). And while substituting them keeping order to capturing group as per OP's needed order since OP wants `2021-04-10T08:46:33-0500` to be changed to `10/04/2021 08:46:33`.

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed 's/\(.*|\)\([^-]*\)-\([^-]*\)-\([^T]*\)T\([^-]*\).*/\1\4\/\3\/\2 \5/' input_file
7304628626|duluth/superior|18490|2016|volvo|gas|49230|automatic|sedan|white|mn|46.815216|-92.178109|10/04/2021 08:46:33
```

`\(.*|\)` - Match till the last occurance of `|` pipe symbol

`\([^-]*\)` - Match till the next occurance of `-` slash. Stores `2021` and `04` which can be returned with `\2` and `\3` back reference

`\([^T]*\)` - Match till the next occurance of `T` capital T. Stores `10` which can be returned with `\4` back reference

`T` - Exclude the `T`

`\([^-]*\)` - Match till the next occurance of - slash. Stores `08:46:33` which can be returned with `\5` back reference

`.*` - Exclude everything else

If your intent is to return only the date and time, you can remove the first back reference

```
$ sed 's/\(.*|\)\([^-]*\)-\([^-]*\)-\([^T]*\)T\([^-]*\).*/\4\/\3\/\2 \5/' input_file
10/04/2021 08:46:33
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -E 's#\|(....)-(..)-(..)T(..:..:..)-....$#|\3/\2/\1 \4#' file
```

Pattern match and using back references format as required.

N.B. The use of the `|` and `$` to anchor the pattern to the last field on the line and the nature of the dashes, colons and the capital T make it most unlikely any other string will match, so a dot can be used to match the digits, but if you like replace `.`'s by `[0-9]`'s. Also the `#` is used as alternative delimiter to the normal `/` in the substitution command `s#...#...#` as `/` appear in the replacement string.